# Run function in background and keep running default program flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I have basic excel file maker function take 2 date arguments

```
public void ExportToExcel(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
```

but thıs function take a long time and I don't want to wait for this preparation time. I want this function to run in the background and not freeze my actionResult

```
        public ActionResult Listele(DateTime? dates, DateTime? datee,string submit)
        {
                var model = db.Transections.ToList();

                DateTime startdate = dates ?? new DateTime(2000, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1);
                DateTime enddate = datee ?? DateTime.Now; ;
                foreach (var item in model.ToList())
                {
                    if (item.Date < startdate || item.Date > enddate)
                    {
                        model.Remove(item);

                    }
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(model.Count());
            if(submit == "report")
                {
                return RedirectToAction("ExportToExcel", "Grid", new { @start = dates, @end = datee });
            }

                return View(model);

        }
```

This action result must be running, not freezing by waiting for this function
and my frontend for thıs action

```
@model IEnumerable<codefirst.Models.Transection>
@using GridMvc.Html
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Listele";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Listele</h2>


<form action="/Grid/Listele" method="get">
   <div class="form-group>
       <label for="q">Start Date</label>
       <input type="date" name="dates" id="dates" class="form-control" />
       <label for="q">End Date</label>
       <input type="date" name="datee" id="datee" class="form-control" />

   </div>
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="cek" name="submit" />
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="report" name="submit" />

@*    @Html.ActionLink("Report", "ExportToExcel", "Grid")*@
</form>




@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(Column =>
  {
      Column.Add(m => m.Buyer).Titled("Buyer").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
      Column.Add(m => m.Seller).Titled("Seller").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
      Column.Add(m => m.Amount).Titled("Amount").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
      Column.Add(m => m.Date).Titled("Date").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).Format("{0:d}");
      Column.Add().Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
      .Encoded(false)
      .Sanitized(false)
      .SetWidth(30)
      .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Düzenle", "Duzenle", "Grid", new { id = o.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" }));
  }).WithPaging(50)
```

ım try to async run like this  export the excel method run correnctly alone but ı cant trigger this function async

```
       public void ExportToExcelasync(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("async geldi");
           Debug.WriteLine(start);
           Debug.WriteLine(end);
           System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => ExportToExcel(start,end));
       }

       public void ExportToExcel(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
```

its my exportexcel func

```
public void ExportToExcel(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Export To Excel çaılıştı");

           Debug.WriteLine(start);
           Debug.WriteLine(end);
           /*
           for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
           {
               Debug.Write(i);
           }

           */


           try
           {//Downloads tablosuna indirmenin kaydı


               Download m = new Download();



               DateTime startdate = start ?? new DateTime(2000, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1); ;

               DateTime enddate = end ?? DateTime.Now;

               Debug.WriteLine(startdate);
               Debug.WriteLine(enddate);
               //each caseler eklenecek seçmezse geçersiz seçerse end date start date den buyukse startla end date degıstırme eklencek




               DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
               //string trim = text.Replace( " ", "_" );
               m.IsExist = false;
               m.CreateDate = now;
               m.EndDate = now;
               m.StartDate = now;
               string name = "Report";
               string date = now.ToString("F");
               date = date.Replace(" ", "_");
               date = date.Replace(",", "_");
               string sonu = ".xls";
               date += sonu;
               name += date;
               m.GuidName = name;
               db.Downloads.Add(m);
               db.SaveChanges();

               //Excelin hazırlanması

               var gv = new GridView();
               var temp = db.Transections.ToList();




               // start 2010  ///// end 2015
               foreach (var item in temp.ToList())
               {
                   if (item.Date < startdate || item.Date > enddate)
                   {
                       temp.Remove(item);

                   }
               }

               gv.DataSource = temp;
               gv.DataBind();
               Response.ClearContent();
               Response.Buffer = true;
               string attachment = "attachment; filename=";
               attachment = attachment + name;
               //attachment = "\"" + attachment +"\"";
               Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
               Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
               Response.Charset = "";
               StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
               HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
               gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
               Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
               Response.Flush();
               Response.End();

               /*

               Download download = new Download();
               download = db.Downloads.Find(m.GuidName);
               download.IsExist = true;
               db.Entry(download).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
               db.SaveChanges();

               */
               //Debug.WriteLine(download.IsExist);





               { /*
               public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
               {
                   using (CustomersEntities entities = new CustomersEntities())
                   {
                       Customer updatedCustomer = (from c in entities.Customers
                                                   where c.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId
                                                   select c).FirstOrDefault();
                       updatedCustomer.Name = customer.Name;
                       updatedCustomer.Country = customer.Country;
                       entities.SaveChanges();
                   }
                   */
               }
               Debug.WriteLine("Return geldi");



               //return NonActionAttribute();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(ex);
               //exception loglanacak
               //return View("Index");

           }


       }
```

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment); this line make a exception and exception is

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Web.dll
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
  at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SetUnknownResponseHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
  at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
  at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String name, String value)
  at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.AddHeader(String name, String value)
  at codefirst.Controllers.GridController.ExportToExcel(Nullable`1 start, Nullable`1 end) in C:\Users\nto_9\source\repos\codefirst\codefirst\Controllers\GridController.cs:line 176
```

what is reason this exception ı cant understand  and how can ı fıx it  can you see me ı was miss thx for help

exception looks like on debugger 
[image: exception on debugger]

ım tryıng to async await

ım change my async method like this and change export to excel method like this but its dont work this still be waith my actionresult for fınıshıng the exporttoexcel method can you see my mistake ?

my async call func

```
       public async Task ExportToExcelasync(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("async geldi");
           Debug.WriteLine(start);
           Debug.WriteLine(end);
           await Task.Run(() => ExportToExcel(start, end));
       }
```

my export to excel func

```
public void ExportToExcel(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Export To Excel çaılıştı");

           Debug.WriteLine(start);
           Debug.WriteLine(end);

           for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
           {
               Debug.Write(i);
           }




           try
           {//Downloads tablosuna indirmenin kaydı


               Download m = new Download();



               DateTime startdate = start ?? new DateTime(2000, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1); ;

               DateTime enddate = end ?? DateTime.Now;

               Debug.WriteLine(startdate);
               Debug.WriteLine(enddate);
               //each caseler eklenecek seçmezse geçersiz seçerse end date start date den buyukse startla end date degıstırme eklencek




               DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
               //string trim = text.Replace( " ", "_" );
               m.IsExist = false;
               m.CreateDate = now;
               m.EndDate = now;
               m.StartDate = now;
               string name = "Report";
               string date = now.ToString("F");
               date = date.Replace(" ", "_");
               date = date.Replace(",", "_");
               string sonu = ".xls";
               date += sonu;
               name += date;
               m.GuidName = name;
               db.Downloads.Add(m);
               db.SaveChanges();

               //Excelin hazırlanması

               var gv = new GridView();

               var temp = db.Transections.ToList();

               // start 2010  ///// end 2015
               foreach (var item in temp.ToList())
               {
                   if (item.Date < startdate || item.Date > enddate)
                   {
                       temp.Remove(item);

                   }
               }

               gv.DataSource = temp;
               gv.DataBind();
               Response.ClearContent();
               Response.Buffer = true;
               string attachment = "attachment; filename=";
               attachment = attachment + name;
               //attachment = "\"" + attachment +"\"";
               Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
               Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
               Response.Charset = "";
               StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
               HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
               gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
               Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
               Response.Flush();
               Response.End();


           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

           }
       }
```

Comment: If it takes a long time to generate the file, then this is the perfect job for a background service e.g. using Hangfire or something, or just a separate windows service). Hand the job off to the background service instead of waiting for the result. Then just send a response to the user telling them how to retrieve the file (e.g. maybe they wait for an email containing a link to it, and/or they go to a specific page and refresh it until they see a link to the file, something like that)

Comment: My use case is a bit diferent actually ı have 2 table and user select 2 date for range later create report  ıtry to export excel report  this report contex is a first table filtered in between 2 date and ı ınsert this report metadata (report name, startdate,enddate ,createdate , isexist etc.) ım list another action my second table and ı try to do if isexist is true(report is ready) show its ready or not report preparing or report was exist so u can download now dont need waith

Comment: I don't see how that causes a problem with my suggestion, to be honest. The point of your question is about how to return the data to the user without freezing the application. The fact the user sends a date range is irrelevant to that. You can still achieve that - the user can send the request containing the dates, you can store the details of each request in a list somewhere (e.g. in a database table, perhaps), and then your background service can process each request in the list one-by-one. Just give the service all the info it needs to process the request without further input.